# bluemix blockchain fmt.println not printed to log

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I deployed the marbles demo to bluemix.  But I do not see its go fmt.println statements in the log.

How does a programmer print to the bluemix log?

--Ken

Answer (score 0):

Ken,

If you are using the built-in deploy (Demo Chaincode tab) it is going to install the Marbles code from the public GitHub repository appropriate for your Bluemix instance.

If you are looking for the fmt.println statements in the logs, you should make sure you are looking at the logs from the chaincode execution (Network tab), not the logs of the peers themselves.
    [image]

If you are looking to edit the demo code to insert your own log statement at specific places, you will need to create your own fork of the public Marbles demo code and not use the built-in deployment. You can either run the Marbles application locally pointing to your Blockchain instance hosted on Bluemix or deploy your edited code to Bluemix as well. You should find additional instructions for those deploy paths in the Readme.md of the Marbles demo repository, depending on your preference. I would recommend running the application locally first.

Hope this helps!